# Silverlight: how to overflow dialogWindow?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I try overflow `myControl.ShowDialog()` - without result. `Canvas.ZIndex` property don't work. I have solution with using JavaScript and Html (absolute position Div), but i want do it with Silverlight tools.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean overlap? Calling `ShowDialog` usually shows the intent of preventing anything else from overlapping the dialog. Try using `Show` instead.

Comment: But if i using `Show` my content under `Show` window can be used.